# How to adapt PPO from continuous to discrete action spaces

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The vanilla clip-PPO algorithm works well for continuous action spaces (MountainCarContinuous) but my question is how to adapt it to discrete action spaces (MountainCar). The RL problem I am struggling with is episodic thus I thought that using MountainCar as an example would be a good start.

Comment: PPO for discrete actions is pretty much the same as continuous actions. The specific way in which you represent the policy is slightly different, e.g. softmax policy instead of Gaussian policy.

Comment: So what's your issue specifically?

Comment: I want to adapt code of PPO-clip to discrete action space. Currently: `mu = tf.layers.dense(l2, A_DIM, activation=tf.nn.tanh)` `sigma = tf.layers.dense(l2, A_DIM, activation=None)` `return tf.distributions.Normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma)`. How to make sofmax?

Comment: I have changed to `probs = tf.layers.dense(l2, self.A_N, activation=tf.nn.softmax)` `return tf.distributions.Categorical(probs = probs)`. After I tried on MountainCar it learns very slowly while MountainCarContinuous learns very fast. Is it because the number of actions is very small?

Comment: Okay great. If you're at a point where your agents is learning something, you're in business. The rest is tweaking. One thing that I might try is remove the softmax activation (so that it outputs logits) and then feed those logits into tf.distributions.Categorical(logits=logits). Although mathematically equivalent, this can be more robust numerically

Comment: I have 3 guidance questions. 1. I sample from this categorical distribution with `tf.squeeze(self.pi.sample(1), axis=0)`. Since MountainCar has only 3 actions the action selected by sampling is likely to be not optimal. I already have reward shaping. Is there a systematic way to increase learning speed? 2. Can I use actor/critic loss/entropy/cross-entropy to find right hyperparameters? 3. In my code actor loss doesn't include critic loss. However I saw codes where discounted critic loss is included in the actor loss. Which way is more robust?

Comment: In the case of a discrete policy, there is no need of parametrizing a standard deviation as for continuous policies, correct? The stochastic role would be played by the categorical distribution I guess